# How to find the expression for the SDF and solve this exercise?

Tags: portfolio-optimization

[image]

I'm struggling to solve point a and b of this exercise, while in  point c I got a very close result to the reciprocal of the relative risk aversion. If you can help me and explain how to do it, it would be really appreciated

Comment: Where is the exercise from?

Comment: I do not know if it is taken from a book or something else, I received it from my university professor in a file of suggested exercises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me write this problem without the vector notation since it is easier:

$$ \max E[v(c_0,c_1)] $$
s.t.
$$
\text { subject to } c_0+\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i p_i=w_0 \text { and }\tilde{c}_1=Y+\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i \tilde{x}_i \text {. }$$

Substituting in the second constraint, the Lagrangean for this problem is:
$$
E\left[v\left(c_0, Y+\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i \tilde{x}_i\right)\right]-\gamma\left(c_0+\sum_{i=1}^n \theta_i p_i-w_0\right),$$

and the first-order conditions are:
$$
E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c_0} v\left(c_0, C_1\right)\right]=\gamma
$$
$$
( \forall i) E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c_1} v\left(c_0, C_1\right) \tilde{x}_i\right]=\gamma p_i.$$

Thus: $$
( \forall i) E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial C_1} v\left(c_0, C_1\right) \tilde{x}_i\right]=p_i E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c_0} v\left(c_0, C_1\right)\right]$$.

From the previous equation you can get:

$$ \frac{E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial C_1} v\left(c_0, C_1\right) \tilde{x}_i\right]}{E\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial c_0} v\left(c_0, C_1\right)\right]} = p_i $$

Equivalently:
$$ E[m \tilde{x}_i] = p_i$$

Where $m$ is the stochastic discount factor.